# javascript jquery add stylesheet if class is present

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, stylesheet, document.write

Can anyone tell me why the following doesn't work in my 'head'

```
<script type="text/javascript">

if ($('.company-color').length){
    document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' href='company-color.css' type='text/css'>");
}

</script>
```

I have a class that is only present on some pages and I want to insert the above stylesheet to the page if the class '.company-color' is present.

Comment: Because at time code is processed, element is not in DOM so your condition will always return 0 (false)

Comment: Why not just always include the stylesheet? (I am sure you have a reason, I am just curious).

Answer (score 2):

use

```
jQuery(function($){
    if ($('.company-color').length){
        $('body').append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='company-color.css' type='text/css'>"); // or to head
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$(function(){
    if ($('.company-color').length > 0){
        $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="company-color.css" type="text/css">');
    }
})
```

You have to use the [append method](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add your css to the head element.